# What server to use?

Tags: android, mysql, server, xmpp, chat

I want to create an Android Application. This application needs to use a server. But the problem with me and like many others is that without an industrial training or experience I have really basic knowledge of what a server does. 
My app needs to do the following:

- Their will be two kinds of clients. Both shall have some kind of interaction between them like seeing each others info based on some search query and then if needed connect to each other via chat.
- The server should store this information in some kind of database maybe a MySQL record or recommend something better that's used in real world.
- For chat, I am thinking of using Ejabberd with xmpp server.

I have searched through net and I have to say, the more I search, the more I get confused. There are Amazon Web Services, Google Cloud Services etc.. But I don't know what specific should I begin with. How should I set-up my server for this specific use.

I know some of us will be skeptical that this question is off-topic or doesn't belong here, but I still want to take a chance to ask this question. Because I know there are millions like me searching where to begin with and if someone helps us get past this barrier, millions of developers could stand a chance. 
I would suggest if someone could explain on How to deal with servers, it would be really appreciated by newbies like me.

Comment: you should definitely improve your question title, adding more context on what's the question about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also struck at the same point in starting and now I have enough wisdom to guide you.

1. First it is useless to get struck with Amazon & Google.
2. You need a domain (You can get one from GoDaddy.com or just get a free subdomain from 000webhost.com)
3. Learn Web Development(Any Language through which you will be able to give response in JSON, I use PHP)
4. Your app does not need any cloud backend, or servers like google cloud. Its all communicating with your own code.
5. Feel free to comment
6. Your domain server will be quite similar to XAMPP

Comment: Thanks for sharing this insight. May I ask what will be the difference between purchasing a server from GoDaddy and getting a free sub-domain?

Comment: If you use GoDaddy you can get a domain like `theguy.com` and if you get a free one you will get it like `theguy.000webhost.com`

Comment: Free one will be better if you just wanna have an app not any website

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is quite simple but the problem with the answer is that its a looong simple answer, I'll only attempt to point you in the right direction.

1. You mentioned search query

   so that means you need some sort of database of which there are countless but for me simplest being php-mysql.
2. You mentioned chat

for this you have to ask yourself, you want autodelivery of chat messages or the user will have to refresh to get new messages? You will need a database to store the messages, again simplest for me is mysql which will probably mean the use will have to refresh to get new messages or you will have to implement some sort of polling to keep on checking for new messages.
Alternatively you can use services like Google's Firebase which has some pretty cool stuff including push notifications which if implemented correctly is lightning fast message delivery and a free account(dont remeber if you get the free account before you pay for your google developer account or after) but its cheap and only a one time payment.

3. You mentioned "real wolrd..."

What I have noticed people doing is doing their development and testing on the free Google Firebase service, some do it on the free AWS packages(some are free forever as long as you dont go beyond a certain limit) as well. There are lots of other service that also provide free trial periods but Firebase and AWS seem to be the most used. After these people are done with developing and testing and ready to push to a live system some still continue on the free packages until there is need to upgrade their packages. Remember, this is not an answer as there is no straight answer, I actually tried adding this response as a comment but I went beyond the character limit hence why its in the answers.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was wondering about XMPP. How should I implement it along with a server that runs php and mysql?

Comment: @TheGuy to be honest I have never used XMPP, But funny enough when I first started learning Android development it was one of the first things that I came across. I tried doing some research on I but ended up thinking it was outdated, I'm not saying it IS outdated just that it seemed to need me to do a lot of reading so I dropped it. That's when I started using firebase, I needed to get things done fast.